# INSERT INTO error MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (total, addy, cc) VALUES ('798' , '123 sadf' , '12124123')' at line 1

```
$total = addslashes(($_SESSION['total']));

$addy = addslashes(($_POST['addy']));

$cc = addslashes(($_POST['cc']));

echo "$total";

echo "$addy";

echo "$cc";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (total, addy, cc) VALUES ('$total' , '$addy' , '$cc')") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use any keyword or reserve name as field or table name.  Rename the order.

Answer (score 7):

In SQL `order` is a reserved word. Instead use:

```
INSERT INTO `order`
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is failing is because "order" is a **keyword** in SQL.

You need to put **backticks** around table names to avoid problems like these.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting ticks around order

```
`order`
```

Answer (score -3):

You forgot "$connection"

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (total, addy, cc) VALUES ('$total' , '$addy' , '$cc')",$connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Col. Shrapnel is correct.  The fact that he is getting a MySQL error shows that the connection is already established.  The mysql_query() function uses an already established connection by default if one is not specified.  The connection is not an issue.  Read the manual -> http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php